# The best terminal emulator which can run scripts and offer good control

Tags: scripts, serial-port, putty, emulation, minicom

I recently moved from Windows 7 to Ubuntu (Not a total noob nor an expert in Linux flavors). **Teraterm** was the terminal emulator I used to connect to my UART enabled devices in Windows. I studied a few in Ubuntu like **Minicom**, **Qodem**, **Cutecom** and even **PuTTY**. I could notice that Minicom is probably the widely used but couldn't get much insight into its scripts offers good control like a `.ttl` macro script offers for Teraterm. (Unfortunately, I don't have much time to experiment with the above myself. Some experience-oriented advice is what I seek) Which would be a better choice for me to run scripts? Or could I get the source code of Teraterm and build it?

PS : XModem support would be a lovely plus too.

Comment: Ubuntu's standard terminal emulator is `gnome-terminal`. It offers you a nice set of visual configuration options and allows you to use the full capabilities of Ubuntu's Bash shell. Please describe what features you are missing in `gnome-terminal` exactly, if any.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I need a _terminal emulator_ program or application for serial port connections (serial communications over UART). @ByteCommander, `gnome-terminal` doesn't have such a capability on its own I think.

Comment: With `minicom`, you may by default use the interpreter [`runscript`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/runscript). I don'tknow `.ttl` language, so I cannot compare. In `minicom`, there is some possibility to use other script interpreters.

Comment: You can get the source code of `teraterm` [here](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/index.html.en). But I suppose it is heavily depending on windows. Maybe it runs with `wine`.

Comment: @ridgy, this looks useful. Will definitely try it out. I could pass a script as some argument to invoke it with `runscript`? I was able to get the source code but I'm a bit skeptical. Coz all over the web, people talk about Teraterm run on Windows. I don't wanna end up with an unstable emulator. Something tried and tested would be great.

Comment: `minicom -s <script>` runs a script at startup. Within the script, you can then again leave `minicom`. From within minicom, you can start a script with `G <script>`. In the configuration, you can define the script directory and the script interpreter (so you are not bound to `runscript`). And yes, it supports xmodem, ymodem, zmodem and kermit.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit this is a good question - did you find a good answer?

Comment: I also completely vouch for minicom. It is one of the most versatile terminal emulator and much more reliable and configurable than other alternatives.